# About datetimefield in UTC format

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJS.
I have 2 datecolumns I would like to be in UTC format. To do that, I use (from the web) :

```
 renderer: function (value) {
                      return moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ');
              },
```

The 2 datecolumns are defined like this :

```
      ..., {
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            header: 'Start Date',
            dataIndex: 'start_date',
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datetimefield',
                itemId: 'startdt',
                allowBlank: false,
                format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
            },
        renderer: function (value) {
                      return moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ');
              },
           },
       {
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            header: 'End Date',
            dataIndex: 'end_date',
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datetimefield',
                itemId: 'enddt',
                allowBlank: false,
            format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',  
            },
        renderer: function (value) {
                      return moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ');
              },
           },...
```

For the model :

```
Ext.define('xxxxx.model.Deployment', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{ 
        name: 'id', 
        type: 'int',
        persist: true
    }, { 
        name: 'name', 
        type: 'string' 
    }, { 
        name: 'start_date', 
        type: 'date',
    }, { 
        name: 'end_date', 
        type: 'date'
    }, ...
```

When I click on one of the datetimefield to edit it, it adds one hour which corresponds to the local time (french) and the format is not the same :

Display : [image]

Edition : [image]

How to prevent this during the edition please ? I spent almost 2 days trying to fix this ...

Thanks for any help

Karim

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the 'moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ');' in the convert or calculate of the model. Something like:

```
{ 
    name: 'end_date', 
    type: 'date',
    convert: function(value) { // or calculate, have a look in the api doc
        return moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ');
    }
}
```

After that remove the timezone conv from renderer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that.datetime fields are not saved anymore (null) and once they are set in the form, they are converted again

Comment: Have you removed the utc logick from the renderer? Anyway, please, create some sample in fiddle, it is hard to help you without working code.